# FIlter Using EF Include against a Non required related Columns

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

I am having 2 related Entity Framework Models  one to many relation exists between the tables

### Contact

```
Id 
Name
....

public ICollection<ContactAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
```

### ContactAddress

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required, MaxLength(150)]
public string Line1 { get; set; }

[ForeignKey(nameof(Contact))]
public int ContactId { get; set; }

public Contact Contact { get; set; } 

[ForeignKey(nameof(Country))]
public int? CountryId { get; set; }

public Country Country { get; set; }

public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
```

The ContactAddress Table the CountryId is  not a required field It can be null in some cases if the country of contact is not known

I am writing a filtering query to retrieve the results of contacts from a specific country ids  and  Filtering query is like below

```
IQueryable<Contact> query = context.Contacts;

    if (searchModel.SelectedCountries?.Count() > 0)
    {
        List<int> country_ids = searchModel.SelectedCountries.Select(x => x.Id).ToList(); //Prepare a list of country ids filtering needs to be applied
        query = query.Include(c => c.Addresses.Where(a => country_ids.Contains((int)a.CountryId)  && a.IsPrimary == true )  );
    }
    
    int totalResultsCount = await query.CountAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The generated sql is like

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM `Contacts` AS `c`
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM `ContactAddresses` AS `c0`
    WHERE `c0`.`CountryId` = 114 AND  `c0`.`IsPrimary`
) AS `t` ON `c`.`Id` = `t`.`ContactId`
ORDER BY `c`.`Id`, `t`.`Id`
```

which returns 497 recods from my database table and this is  equal to the total no of contacts in my table and i can see that the country
filtering is not applied with my EF query.
As soon as i changed LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN in the query manually , i am getting 25 records which is correct for the criterias

' CountryId = 114  IsPrimary =1 '

So how can i enforce the INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN on my IQueryable filtering criteria's ?  Or is there any way to return the results accurately with EF query?

Comment: Do you have DbSet<context.ContactAddresses> that points ContactAddress table?

Comment: Yes i have 2 of them as below  inside DbContext Class
 public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
 public DbSet<ContactAddress> ContactAddresses { get; set; } @Deniz

Comment: Include is for loading related entities. It should not filter main records. Use Where instead.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv How can we apply the Columns of Related records inside the Where clause?

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to get contacts whose addresses match at least one of the  selected filtering countries, then your query should be simply

```
    List<int> country_ids = searchModel.SelectedCountries.Select(x => x.Id).ToList(); //Prepare a list of country ids filtering needs to be applied
    var query = await context.Contacts.Where(c => c.Addresses.Any(a => a.IsPrimary && country_ids.Contains(a.CountryId)).ToListAsync();
```

Any joins will be implicitly generated by EF behind the scenes. There's no need for any `Include()` calls either.

If that `Contains()` call generates a compiler error, you might be able to replace it with `Contains(a.CountryId ?? 0)` though I strongly doubt that will be the case or the alternate will actually compile.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ join, here's an example of query syntax.

```
IQueryable<Contact> query = context.Contacts;

if (searchModel.SelectedCountries?.Count() > 0)
{
    var country_ids = searchModel.SelectedCountries.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

    query = from q in query
            join a in context.ContactAddresses on q.Id equals a.ContactId
            where a.CountryId.HasValue && country_ids.Contains((a.CountryId.Value) && a.IsPrimary
            select q;
}

int totalResultsCount = await query.CountAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: LINQ join vs EF query ON performance aspect  will LINQ makes any difference? This answer works for me but still like to know the advantage of linq  over EF queries if any

Comment: You already use LINQ-to-entities methods like Where, Count in your existing code. It's just a different syntax in my code. Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq

Comment: If i write join in LINQ, i prefer query syntax because i think it's more readable.

Comment: First off, using manual join when having navigation property is just wrong. Second, the result shape of the query is different, and now returns more records (because of join record multiplication).

Comment: @IvanStoev what is the best approach then? I Have Navigation property

Comment: @Sebastian If you need just count, then the answer by Tanveer shows the right way.

Comment: Unfortunately its not just about the count ,  I need the full result set , It is a server side pagination function and count is just one part of that . In addition to count i have to return the complete result set The reason to add IQuery is that i have to append additional conditions on Contact like Email or Name etc based on the search View model

Comment: @Sebastian Full result set is also ok with that answer. However if you want also to inlclude (load) related data, then it should be a combination of your original query +`Where` from the aforementioned answer. All you need is to remember that `Include` is **only** for loading related data, and `Where` is for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look something like the following pseudo code:

```
List<int> country_ids = searchModel.SelectedCountries.Select(x => x.Id).ToList(); //Prepare a list of country ids filtering needs to be applied

  var query =  context.Contacts.Join(context.Addresses,
        contact => contact.Id,
        address => address.ContactId,
        (contact,address) => new { Contact, Address })
       .Where(_ => country_ids.Contains((int)_.Address.CountryId)  && x.Address.IsPrimary == true);
```